# SCALA Creating Functions Syntax

Tags: scala, function

Im a Scala newbie and I get that its a really rich language. One thing that is getting me caught out syntax-wise is on function creation. I understand that braces {} are interpreted by the compiler as being synonymous with parentheses () in many contexts, but the following I still do not quite understand.

The following is the output from Scala REPL:

```
scala> def index = List {}
index: List[Unit]


scala> def index = List ()
index: List[Nothing]
```

Q1.

If I understand the above correctly, I am creating a function called `index` that creates a new List (`new` is omitted because of implicit call to `apply` method right?).

I see that `Unit` (equivalent to `null` in Java?) is the Type of my List when braces {} are used. But Nothing is the type when using parens ().

Q2.

Can someone explain, in simple terms (if possible), the difference between the use of `{}` and `()` in creating functions and also what `Nothing` represents?

---

Edit - So the following are equivalent?

```
def index = List {val a = 1; a}
def index = List ({val a = 1; a})
```

Im also struggling a bit with where the terms `function` and `method` seem to be used interchangeably.

Is it correct to say that both the above can both be considered either a `function` or `method`? 
Or does it depend on who you talk to?

Comment: Re: your edit, those are equivalent. See this post for function vs method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I understand the above correctly, I am creating a function called index that creates a new List (new is omitted because of implicit call to apply method right?).
>
> (new is omitted because of implicit call to apply method right?)

Yes, kind of. `List.apply` constructs the `List` and returns it to your method.

`def index = List {}` creates a *method* called index that creates a new `List` by calling `List.apply`.

> Can someone explain, in simple terms (if possible), the difference between the use of {} and () in creating functions and also what Nothing represents?

The empty curly braces `{}` represent an anonymous function, rather than a simple list of elements. For example I can do:

```
scala> def index = List {val a = 1; a}
index: List[Int]
```

Your method is equivalent to (where the parentheses are omitted):

```
def index = List({})
```

The result of the anonymous function is passed to `apply`. When the braces are empty, the return type of the anonymous function is `Unit`. So we get `List[Unit]`.

`def index = List ()` always returns an empty `List`. However, because you have no annotations, the compiler cannot infer a type from this, so it is inferred as `Nothing`, which is a sub-type of every other type. This allows us to combine a `List[Nothing]` with a `List[Int]` and still compile.

> I see that Unit (equivalent to null in Java?) ...

`Unit` is the return type of a method that doesn't return anything. Similar to `void` in Java, not `null`.

Comment: m-z, thanks very much for helping me out - many thanks. I get it! :)